# how boolean function validation works in apex?

Tags: database, oracle, inventory

```
declare 
  curr_quantity number;
begin
  select quantity
  into curr_quantity
  from stockrecord
  where itemserialnumber = :p28_item_1 
    And inventoryid = :p28_inv_id;

  if curr_quantity < :p28_quantity_1 then
     return false;
  else
     return true;
  end if;
end;

STOCKRECORD(itemserialnumber, inventoryid, quantity).
```

I am trying to validate my quantity at the front end in APEX Oracle with PL/SQL Function Body (Returning Boolean).

Suppose if I have a 500 quantity of an item in table and I set :p28_quantity_1 from 1-250 validation works fine but when i set it to 251 or so on the validation fails. I can't figure out the problem. Any help please.

Comment: Your code looks OK, as far as I can tell. CURR_QUANTITY = 500 for that :P28_INV_ID. If you enter any number larger than 500, it will return FALSE (read: there's not enough quantity on stock). It just doesn't make sense; whether you enter 200 or 400, that code should return TRUE. What difference does 250 make when compared to 251? None. So - please, create a test on apex.oracle.com, provide credentials so that we could have a look.

Comment: yes sir exactly i dont exactly get the point here i tried my code manually on oracle sql developer directly on my database there i get exact answers but i dont know why in apex i am getting this behaviour.

Comment: Where did you put that validation to? P28_QUANTITY_1 item? Or ...?

Comment: yes sir i put that validation to P28_QUANTITY_1 item. i want to validate the quantity on stock when user tries to insert data it should not exceed than the actual quantity that is present in STOCKRECORD.

Comment: When does this validation occur? On Submit?

Comment: i have one button insert which manipulates data(insert, update) into multiple tables namely INVOICE(bill_no,  customer_ID,salesperson_ID, payment_type) BILL_ITEM_DETAILS(item_no, bill_no, inventory_ID) STOCKRECORD(itemserialnumber, inventoryID, quantity).i need to validate data before page is submitted so validation occurs when button is pressed but page is not processed.

Comment: Run the page in debug mode and then review its results. Maybe you'll find something useful.